# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock problem in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

```
Error: missing } in XML expression
source code: http://localhost:3811/Clinic/ScheduleModule/ManageWorkingTime.aspx?ScheduleId=FRXTn%2fX1N8Wy8C%2fdJqQmDjrOEECv%2fRwauMVX6ZTipAM%3d
line: 0, column: 188
code:
<script language='javascript'>$(document).ready(function() {Sexy.alert( "Can not copy files." );});</script>
```

CODE:

```
public static void ShowAsync(string sMessage, MessageBoxTypes sType, Control control, Page pPage)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
            string sMsg = sMessage;
            sMsg = sMsg.Replace("\n", "\\n");
            sMsg = sMsg.Replace("\"", "'");
            sb.Append(@"$(document).ready(function() {");
            sb.Append(@"Sexy." + sType + @"( """ + sMsg + @""" );");
            sb.Append(@"});");
            sb.Append(@"</" + "script>");

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(pPage, typeof(Page), control.ClientID, sb.ToString(), true);
        }
```

if i change true to false in RegisterClientScriptBlock then i get

```
error: $ is not defined
source code: http://localhost:3811/Clinic/ScheduleModule/ManageWorkingTime.aspx?ScheduleId=dH0ry1kng6MwGCRgCxXg8N5nCncbzPzn3TAOEI0tAY4%3d
line: 0
```

i call this popup like:

```
MessageBox.ShowAsync("Can not copy files.", MessageBoxTypes.alert, this, Page);
```

What can be wrong. If i copy this (JQUERY)

```
<script language='javascript'>$(document).ready(function() {Sexy.alert( "Can not copy files." );});</script>
```

into some .aspx page popup works. But if i call it from code behind and daypilot pro in this updatepanel form then i get this error.

Can be problem that two ajax framewroks mixed themself? How to prevent this?

i try with jquery.noConflict but it is the same

```
$.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { Sexy.alert("Can not copy files."); });
```

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the last parameter in RegisterClientScriptBlock from true to false it will not add the script tag anymore. Currently with the setting to true, you have the script tag twice. Not sure what happens, but can't be good :-)

$ sounds like jquery? You don't mention what you are using? I mix ASP.NET Ajax with jquery and that works fine. What Version are you on?

Comment: thx for first explanation. Yes i am using jquery 1.3.1. Can be problem that Jquery and ASP.NET ajax mixed together. We then also DayPilot pro which has own ajax framework. Can i somehowe prevent this?

Comment: As I said, I'm mixing ASP.NET also with jquery 1.3.2. So that should not be the issue. Also, since your query works if you post the javascript into some other asp.net page, this should not be the issue.
Can you remove this DayPilot from that page and see if it helps?